# Is it strange to declare a collection (Set) with the final keyword as described above?

Tags: apex

```
private final Set <String> hoge = new Set <String> {'a', 'b'};
```

Is it strange to declare a collection (Set) with the final keyword as described above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `final` applies to the variable `hoge` meaning a different set of values can't be assigned to the variable. (Unfortunately however, the set that is referenced can be modified as there are no immutable/unmodifiable set classes surfaced in Apex.)

As an indicator from the person who coded it that `hoge` should not change it's a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @ftaro - If you adhere to the [APEX PMD rulesets](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.7/pmd-apex/rules/apex/style.html#VariableNamingConventions), you would do `private final Set <String> HOGE = new Set <String> {'a', 'b'};` - final variables sb all caps

Comment: @cropredy I see! informative!